# In Eclipse folders appear as packages

Tags: eclipse, ide, package

I'm getting an issue where non-src folders are looking like packages, they look completely fine in my natural folder directory.

[image]

The assets folder should be a hierarchy, but isn't.

Thought it was because I was in package explorer but not project explorer, same issue with project explorer.

Comment: This is old, but adding a comment in case it helps.  I ran into similar, and realized that I imported the project wrong.  Deleting it and then re-importing as a maven project did the trick for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe, you right click on your project and choose "Build Path" and "Use as source folder". If it is the case, you can revert the problem by right clicking on your project and selecting "Build Path" and then "Remove from build path".

Answer (score 12):

For me the following worked (in RAD actually): Go to "Project Properties" / "Java Build Path" and mark the Resource Folder as "Source folders on the build path".

[image: Project Window 1]

The Resource Folder (here, `src/main/resources`) appears as filled with classless packages:

[image: Classless packages appear]

Enter the exlcusion pattern "**" to exclude any source path:

[image: Project Window 2]

This solves the problem.

[image: Just folders now]

Comment: Thank you for the exclusion step - just what I nedded

Answer (score 1):

Maven Update fixed my problem easily.

Right click on project,

```
maven->Update Project
```

I suspect that the cause was I run maven commands from command prompt (cmd) directly.

Answer (score 0):

If your simple folder is turning into package format. Be clear that it is not source folder, it is just simple directory like "docs" you want to keep in your Project but eclipse is turning it into Package format. then do below step:

right click on your package -> Build Path -> exclude

[image]